# SVGPathData chrome 48

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg

in chrome 48 was removed: **SVGPathElement.pathSegList**

this page W3C Editor’s Draft 19 January 2016
shows a new way to access to the segments list
https://svgwg.org/specs/paths/#InterfaceSVGPathData

But, how to use it ?
( **in the SVGPathElement the method "getPathData" not exists** )

Answer (score 2):

Chrome has not implemented the new getPathData and setPathData API.
You should use [path data polyfill](https://github.com/jarek-foksa/path-data-polyfill.js):

https://github.com/jarek-foksa/path-data-polyfill.js

Here is a code sample:

```js
//svg code:
//...
//<path d="M0,0 L100,50" id="mypath"></path>
//<script xlink:href="/js/path-data-polyfill.js"></script>
//...

//js code:
var path = document.getElementById('mypath');
var pathdata = path.getPathData();
console.log(pathdata);
console.log(pathdata.length); //2
console.log(pathdata[0].type); //"M"
console.log(pathdata[0].values); //[0,0]
console.log(pathdata[1].type); //"L"
console.log(pathdata[1].values); //[100,50]
pathdata.push({type: "C", values: [100,-50,200,150,200,50]}); //add path segment
path.setPathData(pathdata); //set new path data
console.log(path.getAttribute('d')); //"M0,0 L100,50 C100,-50,200,150,200,50"
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the [SVGPathSeg polyfill](https://github.com/progers/pathseg)? Then you don't need to change any of your existing code.

Comment: Thank you seems to work really well! I made a fix for getTransformToElement

Comment: [getTransformToElement](https://github.com/xosystem/SVG-getTransformToElement-FIX)

Comment: Well, it's 6k more (gzipped) to add, because Chromium devs thought it ok to pull rug out from under folks on existing API (hey, folks, SVG 1.1 is a standard, it's used; it is not a 'working draft'!) without offering a replacement, only a polyfill.  Impolite?  Yes.  Causing thousands of developers to have to spend multiple hours a piece to work around this, with the only offered workaround being a huge polyfill, well that's market share shaking its weight.   Robert, sorry for the frustrated comment on your answer, and thank you for your work on Firefox SVG, I very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Robert Longson's suggestion is a good one for now. The API you are referring to (**getPathData**, **setPathData**) is all brand new and has not been implemented yet. There might also be changes before it is implemented and available.

Comment: Thank you seems to work really well!,  I made a fix for [getTransformToElement](https://github.com/xosystem/SVG-getTransformToElement-FIX)

Comment: so they took out a working feature and replaced it with nothing??

Answer (score 1):

Fall back to

```
path.setAttribute('d', ...)
```

for a browser found to be incompatible with SVG 1.1.

Furthermore, if the browser is of a brand that *previously* supported SVG 1.1, then print a message suggesting that the user *upgrade back* to the older version (and possibly even consider a different, more stable, brand of browser, one that may have been designed with more consideration of the time required of developers to work around the lack of features that once worked perfectly well, and then were removed for the purpose of replacing them with nothing, as ktejik has noted).