# SVG numberOfItems property not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg

Our website suddenly stopped working on Chrome (just chrome) after the latest update...

The error given is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'numberOfItems' of undefined
```

This is where the numberOfItems property is used:

```
// Absolutize and parse path to array
  , parse: function(array) {
      /* if it's already is a patharray, no need to parse it */
      if (array instanceof SVG.PathArray) return array.valueOf()

      /* prepare for parsing */
      var i, il, x0, y0, x1, y1, x2, y2, s, seg, segs
        , x = 0
        , y = 0

      /* populate working path */
      SVG.parser.path.setAttribute('d', typeof array === 'string' ? array : arrayToString(array))

      /* get segments */
      segs = SVG.parser.path.pathSegList


      for (i = 0, il = segs.numberOfItems; i < il; ++i) {
        seg = segs.getItem(i)
        s = seg.pathSegTypeAsLetter
etc. (I didn't put the whole loop)
```

Why did SVG and Javascript stop being able to read this property after the latest Chrome update? What could be a good fix?

Thanks!!

Comment: Check the value of `segs` in debugger.

Comment: Their is a working draft that's being implemented at the moment around SVG 'path' elements. It's possible their is a bug (https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/paths.html#InterfaceSVGPathElement). I'd try Canary and see if the issue is present in it or not.

Comment: Unrelated: don't omit `;`s. This will bite you. Hard.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34919405/svgpathdata-chrome-48

Comment: This issue was solved in svg.js as soon as it was known (released 30.11.2015). So you just have to update your version

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Chrome [removed the pathSeg](https://www.chromestatus.com/features#pathseg) interface in version 48.

[There's more information in their public issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=539385)

There's also [an issue tracking the implementation of the replacement API](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=545467) in the meantime there are [polyfills available to reinstate support for the old API](https://github.com/progers/pathseg)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I only have a small problem though... I've trying doing the polyfill but I still get the error. This is my project: https://github.com/jeratt/Citywide-Dashboard

I've already pasted "<script src="pathseg.js"></script>" into index.php and added the pathseg.js file to the main directory (as well as trying a bunch of other subfolders. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!